# How to get minimum distance from point to polygon using openmap?

Tags: java, geolocation, geometry, openmap

Given a point coordinates(latitude/longitude) and an array of latitude/longitude representing a polygon. How do I get the distance from the point to the polygon, using OpenMap API?

Comment: I was planning to convert latitude/longitude to x/y coordinates and use JTS(java geometry api) to calculate the distance. So far I couldn't find much documentation in OpenMap API. I'm still not used to the API.

Comment: do you know anything about the polygones, are they all concave/convex? Do you know if a point has an edge to it's nearest 2 neighbours? Those things are to be considered!

Comment: There can be concave or convex polygons, and the point may be anywhere. That's one of the reasons I'm looking for an API to do the job.